# robo 3t - Aggregate query on array fails

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

**Setup:**
Documents in parent collection have a field children with child identifiers. Documents in the child collection have the identifier in a customId field not _id. A single identifier from the 'children' field may match multiple children.

**What's wrong:**
This query

```
db.getCollection('parent').aggregate({$lookup: {from: "child", localField: "children", foreignField:"customId", as:"joinedChildren"}})
```

runs correctly in mongo shell but causes

```
Error:
TypeError: pipeline[(pipeline.length - 1)] is undefined :
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1292:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1
```

in robo3T.

Answer (score 2):

The problem went away when I wrap the query in []

```
db.getCollection('parent').aggregate([{$lookup: {from: "child", localField: "children", foreignField:"customId", as:"joinedChildren"}}])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
db.Parent.Aggregate([{$lookup :
{
From :"child",
localFied:"children",
foreignField:"customId",
as : "joinedchildren"
}
}])
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the existing one? It is even introducing more syntax error and basically a plagiarism of the existing answer.